# Pairing BluetoothDevice programmatically in Android - connection issue

Tags: android, reflection, bluetooth, uuid

I've got to write an app which has the prerequisite to allow in-app bluetooth pairing.

Googling around, i found out there's a way of programmatically pair a BluetoothDevice with API level < 19:

```
Method createBondMethod = BluetoothDevice.class.getMethod("createBond");
Boolean paired = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(device);
if (paired.booleanValue()) {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Pairing bluetooth device succeded.");

} else {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "Pairing bluetooth device failed.");
}
```

It's a very hacky solution, reflection on private methods is quite never a good solution.. but it seems to be the only one available.

I tried it.. and I manage to pair my tablet with another Bluetooth device (it's neither a smartphone nor a tablet..).

After pairing the two devices, I need to create a BluetoothSocket and connect it.

Here the problem comes:

```
BluetoothSocket socket = null;
try {
    final UUID uuid = this.mDevice.getUuids()[0].getUuid();
    socket = this.mDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    socket.connect();
    Log.e(LOGTAG, "Connected to the socket");
    this.onBluetoothDeviceConnected(socket, this.mDevice);
    return;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // handling exception
}
```

My `this.mDevice` is the paired device and it's not null.. But it's got no UUID, in fact the method `BluetoothDevice.getUuids()` returns a null value.

Have you ever been facing the same problem? Have you got any working solution to this annoing problem?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem now. The getUuid() returns null when it have a problom getting the UUID.  speaking to the manufacturer of my device they told me that my device don't support UUID's.
I'm currently trying to solve this. if I'll succeed I will tell you

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. 
To critique or request clarification from an author, 
leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, 
and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.